# hbase 0.92 and opentsdb compatibility

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

I am trying to migrate opentsdb to use hbase 0.92, since for some reason hbase 0.90.x, which uses a branch-versioned hadoop core jar, does not play well with any release of hadoop. Sadly after I configured and hooked up everything, I constantly got the following error in hbase's log

```
2012-05-02 21:48:25,725 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion: No such column family in batch put
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family t does not exist in region tsdb,,1335994142141.79b560b1ba606c2f9eef533ddc31e86e. in table {NAME => 'tsdb', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'id', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE',REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '3', TTL => '2147483647', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'name', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '3', TTL => '2147483647', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.checkFamily(HRegion.java:3907)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.checkFamilies(HRegion.java:2184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.doMiniBatchPut(HRegion.java:1790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.put(HRegion.java:1723)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.multi(HRegionServer.java:3062)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1326)
```

when I searched through opentsdb's frontend UI, I got this error

```
org.hbase.async.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family t does not exist in region tsdb,,1335994142141.79b560b1ba606c2f9eef533ddc31e86e. in table {NAME => 'tsdb', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'id', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '3', TTL => '2147483647', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}, {NAME => 'name', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '3', TTL => '2147483647', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]}

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.checkFamily(HRegion.java:3907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getScanner(HRegion.java:1422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getScanner(HRegion.java:1401)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.openScanner(HRegionServer.java:2054)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1326)

Caused by RPC: OpenScannerRequest(table="tsdb", key=[0, 0, 1, 79, -95, 75, -16], family="t", qualifier=null, start_key=[0, 0, 1, 79, -95, 75, -16], stop_key=[0, 0, 1, 79, -95, -68, -9], max_num_kvs=4096, populate_blockcache=true, attempt=1, region=RegionInfo(table="tsdb", region_name="tsdb,,1335994142141.79b560b1ba606c2f9eef533ddc31e86e.", stop_key=""))
    at org.hbase.async.NoSuchColumnFamilyException.make(NoSuchColumnFamilyException.java:56) ~[asynchbase-1.2.0.jar:bead2c4]
    at org.hbase.async.NoSuchColumnFamilyException.make(NoSuchColumnFamilyException.java:32) ~[asynchbase-1.2.0.jar:bead2c4]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.deserializeException(RegionClient.java:1182) ~[asynchbase-1.2.0.jar:bead2c4]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.deserialize(RegionClient.java:1159) ~[asynchbase-1.2.0.jar:bead2c4]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:1080) ~[asynchbase-1.2.0.jar:bead2c4]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:82) ~[asynchbase-1.2.0.jar:bead2c4]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:470) ~[netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:443) ~[netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:80) ~[netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.handleUpstream(RegionClient.java:936) ~[asynchbase-1.2.0.jar:bead2c4]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$RegionClientPipeline.sendUpstream(HBaseClient.java:1974) ~[asynchbase-1.2.0.jar:bead2c4]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274) [netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261) [netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:351) [netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:282) [netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:202) [netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44) [netty-3.2.7.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_24]
```

Is it because asynchbase-1.2 does not play well with hbase 0.92. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you did this, but this clearly shows that you incorrectly created the tables.  OpenTSDB needs two tables, `tsdb` and `tsdb-uid` (names are configurable).  The `tsdb` table has a single column family, `t`, and `tsdb-uid` has two: `name` and `id`.

From the excerpt above, it is clear that your `tsdb` table has the column families of `tsdb-uid`:

`{NAME => 'tsdb', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'id', ...}, {NAME => 'name', ...}]}`

Use OpenTSDB's `src/create_table.sh` script to create the tables.  With it you can't get it wrong.

Comment: dude, you made my day! The reason I did not use the script was because "COMPRESSION => none" is not accepted by hbase 0.92 shell. So now I just deleted "COMPRESSION => none" in the script and created the table with it. HBase and OpenTSDB can talk to each other now. However, is it the right way to create table? Do you have any suggestions on it?

Comment: If you wanted to set `COMPRESSION => NONE`, just set it as an environment variable before running the script: `HBASE_HOME=path/to/hbase COMPRESSION=NONE ./src/create_table.sh`

Comment: I was saying COMPRESSION => NONE is not an accepted syntax for HBase 0.92 shell, so original create table script would fail to create tsdb and tsdb-uid tables with that env variable. I worked around this issue by excluding COMPRESSION=>NONE, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: `COMPRESSION => NONE` should be accepted by HBase 0.92 too, the only problem I am aware of is that in 0.92 there is a bug that prevents `COMPRESSION => none` (lower case "none") from working.  PS: Can you accept my answer?  :)